# How to import some actionscript files from flash builder 3 to flash builder 4?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I am having great difficulty getting my existing actionscript files into flash builder 4.

Basically, I have fully working flex builder 3 project, in a flex builder 3 workspace.

I now have flash builder 4, and a new flash builder 4 work space.

I dont want to "import an existing project into workspace", as I need to move the project out of the old workspace into the new one, and only want the source files not any fp3 specific config baggage.

I Created a new flash builder 4 project, then manually copied using the file system all the .as files in their package structure over to the new project src location.  However, now flash builder "sees" these files and packages icons are greyed out and doesnt compile them (e.g. if you make a syntax error, it doesnt flag it).

So next I tried importing them (file->import->general->file system), but then it just creates mad duplicate strucutres, so i end up with src/com/mydomain/mydomain/package or even the entire absolute path duplicated under the project instead of src/com/....  When It does this, delete the project, and start over.  Ive tried every logical combination of directories and options.

There must be an easy way to move some source files into a project, and get flash builder to "see" them?  currently my only option now is to hand create each as file manually and cut and paste the contents, which is going to take some time.

Anyone have a easy way of moving as source files?

Comment: I haven't used FB4, but can you right click on those grayed out items - is there an add to project option?

Comment: Did you try refreshing the src folder - right click on src folder in the navigation and select refresh

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and used the "exiting projects into workspace" option, which is not ideal as its presumably not clean (will have FB3 specific crud and settings imported), but works.

Comment: Update: Importing the whole projects, I ended up with links to the old workspaces.  To fix, I edited the .project file from:

 <linkedResources>
  <link>
   <name>[source path] src</name>
   <type>2</type>
   <location>D:/dev/flexbuilder/test/src</location>
  </link>
 </linkedResources>

To:
  <link>
   <name>[source path] src</name>
   <type>2</type>
   <locationURI>DOCUMENTS/flashAPI/src</locationURI>
  </link>

Answer (score 0):

I just moved from a Flex 3.5 project to a Flex 4 project and it's been ok so far. I pasted all my source files as a folder inside the new project's src folder. One MXML file I had didn't compile for some reason. So I just had to copy/paste that one inside a new MXML file and it worked.